# what are the characteristics of a good error correcting code?

Tags: coding-theory

A posteriori  information of a bit = intrinsic info. from that particular bit + extrinsic information from the code excluding that bit.

Let's say we are operating at a decent SNR per bit and expecting a decent Bit-error-rate (BER) of $10^{-5} $.

What are things that matter here?
Like for example minimum distance...
However it is clear that other things too matter. 
Could someone throw some light on them.

Comment: I am not an expert but if bit flips are not iid, then maybe there is a specific class of errors that occur. And for these errors there might be dealt with well by a particular code?

Comment: Another thing to consider is how efficient a decoding algorithm there is for the code.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I agree that the decoder complexity is critical...you can even argue that it is the most important criteria. For example there are many algebraically defined codes with very good properties (dmin,...) that are not used because of decoding complexity. Also there are "random" codes that have very good BER/BLER performance that are not practically implementable.

Comment: Of course the decoding complexity is taken into account. But the purpose of asking this question is know what all things matter at high SNRs, like 1. Does intrinsic information gives more information?  2. Does extrinsic information gives the required information ? If extrinsic info. matters, then what should be the structure of error correcting code which will give desired information. 3. Or only minimum distance  matters (but definitely not, clearly from repetitive code's performance) ?

Answer (score -1):

Don't over think this.

The gist is simple. You have M bits of message and add N bits for checksums and error corrections in the data of D bits overall (D = M + N). Ideally you'd like to have N be zero. The gist is that the message efficiency is M/(M+N).

The rub here is do you design the checksums and error correction for just one error, or two errors, or three errors and so on. The more errors that you're checking for then the bigger N will get for some fixed message of size M bits.

Also it will take more bits to correct the error than it will take to just detect the error.

I guess the last consideration would be can you request that the message be resent if it is too garbled?

So for a message of size M you decide that you'll design the code to detect and correct 4 bits. But you decide that if more than 2 bits are corrupted that you'll ask for the message to be resent rather than risk that there are actually 5 or more errors in the data such that the detection/correction scheme is invalid.

If the message can't be resent then you'd have to design for more detection/correction capability.

Comment: Don't underthink it either, Max.